# How does spring the converter interface guarantee thread-safety of implementations

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, converters

I have a spring api. I have created some converters using the Converter interface found in the org.springframework.core.convert.converter package. The interface documentation states "Implementations of this interface are thread-safe and can be shared". I was able to add mutable class fields to my converter implementations. If I can do this, then what mechanism ensures thread-safety?

Comment: That wording is misleading. What's it trying to say is that implementations should be thread-safe, ie. made to by be their developers.

Comment: Maybe they also meant that the implementations included in that Spring library are thread safe.

Comment: @Sotiros Delimanolis I could believe them meaning it’s the developers responsibility by convention. Similar is expected of the developer when the component annotations are used in a singleton scope. If so, I wish it was firmly documented as that. Otherwise it feels like a guesstimate.